# subtable, extended table ExtJS

Tags: extjs

subtable or extended table, I do not know how to be more correct to call it.

I need to implement the table with the following structure:

Car | Number | Price | Date |

Mazda | 0122335 | $20000 | 01.08.10 |

____________________________| $19999 | 02.08.10 |

____________________________| $19500 | 03.08.10 |

____________________________| $19000 | 04.08.10 |

Toyota| 0254785 | $50000 | 01.08.10 |

_BMW | 1212222 | $80000 | 04.08.10 |

____________________________| $75000 | 06.08.10 |

____________________________| $70000 | 08.08.10 |

____________________________| $65000 | 10.08.10 |

____________________________| $60000 | 12.08.10 |

____________________________| $55000 | 15.08.10 |

as you see, one row of Сar - we have several lines with Price and Date.

I not found examples of such a structure, so please help on the forum. Maybe someone knows how to implement such a table.
Thks.

Answer (score 3):

Grouping grid?
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grouping.html

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking (but you were a bit faster). @fenuk : You should have a look at the [ExtJS examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/). Quite a lot of things are covered there (the forums can be helpful too if you're stuck).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perhaps you're right, it is necessary to magic some standard examples